# Javascript not loading in browser(Miui10 Global8.9.6 beta_Redmi note4)

Tags: javascript, miui-10, redmi-note-4

I had written a custom HTML/javascript application and wanted to run it in a android browser on my Redmi Note4.

Firstly I activated javascript in all the browsers (MIUI default browser,chrome,firefox).Then,I tried opening the file directly from the file manager,but it only loaded html but not javascript.

Afterthat ,I pasted the file path

> content://com.mi.android.globalFileexplorer.myprovider/external_files/...

in the browser but even in this case only html was recognised but not javascript.However as seen from this forum thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41430244/chrome-on-android-not-loading-local-website-javascript-and-css),this solution has worked on other phones.
Is there any way to detect javascript in MIUI10 OS?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently,the Redminote4 file manager doesn't recognise the link between separate html/css/javascript files(even though it get's perfectly recognised in a desktop environment).

The only option left is to embed all your html/css/javascript code into one large html file(not a good practise!) and open this file directly from the file manager.